# Mid 80's DIP8 and DIP14 Chip Identification

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, dip

Working on a mid-80's engine control unit, I have spent the better part of two days finding datasheets/pinouts for two mystery chips. I originally thought they were 4000 series logic chips, but no such numbers exist.

The unit is from a gen and appears to be a Ford EEC-IV controlling throttle body injection, on an accessory board labeled "FBC", for "Feedback Carburetor"

The were apparently made by Signetics (now NXP) - due to the S on the chip.
However, I cannot find any datasheet for either the 4501 or 4514 part:

[image]
[image]

The full markings are:

IC1: 4501 8408 S 005BB

IC3: 700002BB 8422 S 4514

I was able to determine that:

**IC1 has +5V on Pin 3 & GND on pin 12**

**IC3 has +5V on Pin 4 & GND on pin 8**

I *suspect* that 8408 / 8422 are date codes. IC3 smells like some sort of OpAmp with nonstandard pinout!?

For what it's worth, here are schematics I drew of the periphery around them:

[image]
[image]

Any hints, however silly, are appreciated!

**UPDATE** After getting my hands on some high resolution images of other boards, some of them have:

IC3 = S4501 = S4017 = RCA 340; but they are all marked (70)005BB

IC1 = S4514 = S4513 = S3501; but they are all marked 700002BB

It appears that this is the "true" model number of an ASIC possibly. I have not found any cross mappings of internal part numbers to real part numbers as for the other board yet.

Comment: 7422 , 4 input NAND gates maybe, 8 version for higher temperature range in this case

Comment: The 7422 doesn't have GND on Pin12; I suspect the 8422 being a date code.

Comment: Yes, I found some links refers to 700002BB, it is some ic used in avionics/transport made by Intersil in 2003.

Comment: It is often very useful to be able to determine which pins are ground and which one is the power supply to identify a device. Your schematic doesn't seem to give information about that.

Comment: Most likely ASICs. Looks like a Signetics logo on there. The best way to figure out a little black box is to measure inputs and outputs and have a guess at the function. If you need to replace them, that's going to be hard.

Comment: You have a transistor with the base tied to ground and the collector and emitter tied together... Something must be wrong there.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser As for IC4, maybe I should not have used the NPN circuit symbol; it's a TO92 with "RAC" labeled on the silkscreen; I suspect a shunt regulator based on that. Taking measurements will be my next step; I'm still looking at how to do that best. Could be ASICs, but there are only those two DIPs on this daughterboard with a number of passives. I will definitely update on findings.

Comment: +1 to OP - this is a *great* reference as to what a part identification question should look like for EE.SE.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický The higher-temperature version of the 74 series is the 54 series, not 84 (which I don't think exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe to have identified the chips by elimination based to supply voltages, VCC and GND pins.

**IC1 = LM339 or pin-compatible**

**IC3 = TI5534 or pin-compatbile**

I have redrawn and simplified the schematics while hopefully making no mistakes and the circuits seem to become more understandable and sensible:

[image]
[image]

For now, I won't accept it as answer, but wanted to provide it as potential answer. Should anything change about my assumptions, I will update the post.